# Uploads from my mobile phone via filepicker.io are failing

Tags: mobile, upload, filepicker.io

I have some very simple javascript that works on the desktop and through the dialog pop-ups on the filepicker.io developer portal. However, every single attempt through my Samsung Galaxy S using the AT&T network simply hangs.

Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

I would love to help resolve this issue, please contact support@filepicker.io with specifics of the files being uploaded and the browser you're using and we can resolve any problem you're seeing.